# tinymce change with php

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm trying to connect the tinymce advimage to my set of uploaded user photos, **whithout** buying the fimagemanager and/or filemanager. I obviously need to connect the server, but the browser doesn't recognize the php. what should I do?

Comment: The duplicate is actually the duplicate of this one here. But thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have done it in the past, so its prob not the most optimal solution ;)

If you are using the `external_image_list_url` option then you can point it to a loader script that will create your image js array.

```
// Image list
external_image_list_url : "http://example.com/image_list.php",
```

Then you can dynamically create the js image array, and output as `Content-Type:text/javascript`
**image_list.php**

```
<?php 
$directory = './uploads/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.bmp}';

$js = 'var tinyMCEImageList = new Array('.PHP_EOL;
foreach (glob($directory,GLOB_BRACE) as $file){
    if (is_file($file) && @getimagesize($file) != FALSE) {
        $js .= "\t".'["'.basename($file).'", "http://example.com/uploads/'.basename($file).'"],'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$js = rtrim($js,','.PHP_EOL).PHP_EOL.");".PHP_EOL;

header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
echo $js;
?>
```

The result would resemble something like:

```
var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(
    // Name, URL
    ["some_image.png", "http://example.com/uploads/some_image.png"],
    ["some_image2.png", "http://example.com/uploads/some_image2.png"]

);
```

Comment: the problem is that the html doesn't recognize the php itself, and the images list is dinamic

Comment: The problem is actually the php, not the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your webserver needs to be able to handle php files correctly.
Make yure your server supports php, php is installed and your server configuration is set to support php files.